# that perhaps intended?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I'm wondering how to understand "that perhaps intended" in the following. It feels out of place. Without it, the sentence would be fairly understandale as "The perlocutionary effect might be that he goes and mends them." The subject "The perlocutionary effect" would be followed by an auxiliary and a verb, and a that-clause. I don't know how to interpret "that perhaps intended" in the structure.

> E.g. a wife might say to her husband ‘Have you remembered to mend the steps?’ The perlocutionary effect might be **that perhaps intended**, that he goes and mends them. Or it might be that he loses his temper, or simply replies ‘Yes, dear’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**that** refers back to **effect**, and **perhaps intended** is a [participle phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm) which modifies **that**. The meaning is therefore

> that perhaps intended -> the effect that is perhaps intended.

In my opinion, it is an unnecessarily complex construction... but when it follows an obscure word like **perlocutionary**, it's probably not reasonable to expect clear writing.

Comment: Could I say, "The perlocutionary effect might be as  perhaps intended, that is, he goes and mends them"?

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, you can.